I have accidentally created a new Discord user-ID - is there a way to say this-unclaimed-profile-is-me-too and merge them?
I see the likes of How to get past Discord's "This is an unclaimed account"?, but wasn't quick enough to stop myself completing the workflow. Discord asks for a name, and does't warn you with the likes of "we see you've previously logged into Discord in this browser, do you want to log in again, because if not you're in a new-user workflow and may have some regret later"
So I'd like a "merge users" workflow, cos I end up in new Discord groups and see that my 30 groups on the left are missing and the banner at the top "this is an unclaimed discord".  It must exist somewhere in the complicated settings menu, right?
By contrast the workflow for new StackExchange encounters (like this one 'webapps' is new to me today, never goes wrong - their UX team approached the same problem differently).
